# Somar valores de linhas e colunas e armazenar em vetor

Tags: c, array, matriz

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um algoritmo no qual preciso armazenar o total das somas de cada linha e cada coluna em vetores distintos.

Por exemplo: vetorA de 5 posições recebe o total da soma de 5 linhas da matriz, cada resultado armazenado em uma posição do vetor.

Pensei em resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

```
void processarDados(int matriz[4][5], int vetorA[5], int vetorB[4])
{
    int i, j;
    int soma = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            vetorA[j] = matriz[i][j];  // vetorA armazena os valores das posições [i][j] da matriz até J ou 5;              
            soma = soma + vetorA[j]; // É feito a soma dos valores encontrados no vetorA;
            vetorA[j] = soma; //O resultado da soma é armazenado novamente no mesmo vetor.
        }
    }
```

Mas não encontro os valores esperados, por exemplo, digito uma sequência de 1 até 5, o resultado deveria ser 15 porém ele me retorna 92... Valor muito distante do esperado. O código não está pronto mas vou deixar para que vejam.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

    void limparTela();
    void saltarLInha();

    void receberDados(int matriz[4][5]);
    void processarDados(int matriz[4][5], int vetorA[4], int vetorB[5]);
    void resultadoDados(int matriz[4][5], int vetorA[4], int vetorB[5]);

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

            int matriz[4][5];
            int vetorA[5];
            int vetorB[4];

        receberDados(matriz);
        processarDados(matriz, vetorA, vetorB);
        resultadoDados(matriz, vetorA, vetorB);

        return 0;      

    }

    void limparTela()
    {
        system("cls");
    }

    void saltarLInha()
    {
        printf("\n");
    }

    void receberDados(int matriz[4][5])
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                printf("Insira o valor da posição [%i][%i]: ", i, j);
                scanf("%i", &matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void processarDados(int matriz[4][5], int vetorA[5], int vetorB[4])
    {
        int i, j;
        int soma = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                vetorA[j] = matriz[i][j];                
                soma = soma + vetorA[j];
                vetorA[j] = soma;
            }
        }
    }

    void resultadoDados(int matriz[4][5], int vetorA[5], int vetorB[4])
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                printf("[%i] ", matriz[i][j]);
            }

            saltarLInha();

        }



        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("[%i] ", vetorA[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Na função `processaDados`não há necessidade de usar a variável `soma`, tudo pode ser feito de maneira bem simples. Por exemplo:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    vetorA[i] = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        vetorA[i] += matriz[j][i];
    }
}
```

As funções `limparTela` e `saltarLinha` também não têm necessidade de existir, pois são comandos básicos de uma única linha. Evite sempre adicionar código "redundate", porque só vai dificultar a leitura do código.